# Execute copy command as admin on cmd

Tags: java, swing

So my problem is i have a button that i want to run a copy command on cmd as administrator because the propose of that button is to copy files to the directry fonts but it gives access denied because the directory fonts needs administrator privileges.

The code that i have is this:

```
try {
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();;
            if(e.getState()) {
            rt.exec("runas /user:administrator cmd /c start /MIN cmd.exe /C" + "copy E:\\automation\\bin\\automation\\TitiliumWeb\\* C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\");
            }
            else if(d.getState()) {
                rt.exec("runas /user:administrator cmd /c start /MIN cmd.exe /C" + "copy D:\\automation\\bin\\automation\\TitiliumWeb\\* C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The result is that it doesnt do anything because it need the password of the administrator but i don't know where to put it.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you want to make use of custom fonts, this is the wrong way to do it.  Don’t try to permanently alter the user’s machine.  Embed the fonts in your application, access them with [Class.getResourceAsStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29), and pass that InputStream to [Font.createFont](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Font.html#createFont%28int,java.io.InputStream%29).

Comment: Can you give an example on how to use?

Answer (score 0):

Even if it were possible to do this without manually entering a password, it would be inappropriate to alter the user’s computer.

You have added the `swing` tag to your question, so I assume you need some custom fonts for use in a Swing program.  The proper way to do this is:

- Include the font files in your application.  Every IDE has a “resources” section for this.
- At runtime, read the embedded font files with [Class.getResourceAsStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29).
- Pass the returned InputStream to [Font.createFont](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Font.html#createFont%28int,java.io.InputStream%29).
- Use [deriveFont](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Font.html#deriveFont%28float%29) to obtain the size you want.

The code might look like this:

```
Font font;
try (InputStream fontSource =
    MyApplication.class.getResourceAsStream("TitilliumWeb-Regular.ttf")) {

    font = Font.createFont(fontSource);

    // 12 pt font
    font = font.deriveFont(12f);

} catch (IOException | FontFormatException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Required font is corrupted", e);
}
```